# Rewrite the given class to use composition rather than inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, composition

```
// Fig. 9.8: BasePlusCommissionEmployee.java
// private superclass members cannot be accessed in a subclass.

public class BasePlusCommissionEmployee extends CommissionEmployee
{
   private double baseSalary; // base salary per week

   // six-argument constructor
   public BasePlusCommissionEmployee( String first, String last, 
      String ssn, double sales, double rate, double salary )
   {
      // explicit call to superclass CommissionEmployee constructor
      super( first, last, ssn, sales, rate );

      setBaseSalary( salary ); // validate and store base salary
   } // end six-argument BasePlusCommissionEmployee constructor

   // set base salary
   public void setBaseSalary( double salary )
   {
      baseSalary = ( salary < 0.0 ) ? 0.0 : salary;
   } // end method setBaseSalary

   // return base salary
   public double getBaseSalary()
   {
      return baseSalary;
   } // end method getBaseSalary

   // calculate earnings
   @Override // indicates that this method overrides a superclass method
   public double earnings()
   {
      // not allowed: commissionRate and grossSales private in superclass
      return baseSalary + ( commissionRate * grossSales );
   } // end method earnings

   // return String representation of BasePlusCommissionEmployee
   @Override // indicates that this method overrides a superclass method
   public String toString()
   {
      // not allowed: attempts to access private superclass members   
      return String.format( 
         "%s: %s %s\n%s: %s\n%s: %.2f\n%s: %.2f\n%s: %.2f", 
         "base-salaried commission employee", firstName, lastName, 
         "social security number", socialSecurityNumber, 
         "gross sales", grossSales, "commission rate", commissionRate, 
         "base salary", baseSalary );
   } // end method toString
} // end class BasePlusCommissionEmployee

// Fig. 9.4: CommissionEmployee.java
// CommissionEmployee class represents a commission employee.

public class CommissionEmployee extends Object
{
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private String socialSecurityNumber;
   private double grossSales; // gross weekly sales
   private double commissionRate; // commission percentage

   // five-argument constructor
   public CommissionEmployee( String first, String last, String ssn, 
      double sales, double rate )
   {
      // implicit call to Object constructor occurs here
      firstName = first;
      lastName = last;
      socialSecurityNumber = ssn;
      setGrossSales( sales ); // validate and store gross sales
      setCommissionRate( rate ); // validate and store commission rate
   } // end five-argument CommissionEmployee constructor

   // set first name
   public void setFirstName( String first )
   {
      firstName = first; // should validate
   } // end method setFirstName

   // return first name
   public String getFirstName()
   {
      return firstName;
   } // end method getFirstName

   // set last name
   public void setLastName( String last )
   {
      lastName = last; // should validate
   } // end method setLastName

   // return last name
   public String getLastName()
   {
      return lastName;
   } // end method getLastName

   // set social security number
   public void setSocialSecurityNumber( String ssn )
   {
      socialSecurityNumber = ssn; // should validate
   } // end method setSocialSecurityNumber

   // return social security number
   public String getSocialSecurityNumber()
   {
      return socialSecurityNumber;
   } // end method getSocialSecurityNumber

   // set commission employee's gross sales amount
   public void setGrossSales( double sales )
   {
      grossSales = ( sales < 0.0 ) ? 0.0 : sales;
   } // end method setGrossSales

   // return commission employee's gross sales amount
   public double getGrossSales()
   {
      return grossSales;
   } // end method getGrossSales

   // set commission employee's rate
   public void setCommissionRate( double rate )
   {
      commissionRate = ( rate > 0.0 && rate < 1.0 ) ? rate : 0.0;
   } // end method setCommissionRate

   // return commission employee's rate
   public double getCommissionRate()
   {
      return commissionRate;
   } // end method getCommissionRate

   // calculate commission employee's pay
   public double earnings()
   {
      return commissionRate * grossSales;
   } // end method earnings

   // return String representation of CommissionEmployee object
   @Override // indicates that this method overrides a superclass method
   public String toString()
   {
      return String.format( "%s: %s %s\n%s: %s\n%s: %.2f\n%s: %.2f", 
         "commission employee", firstName, lastName, 
         "social security number", socialSecurityNumber, 
         "gross sales", grossSales, 
         "commission rate", commissionRate );
   } // end method toString
} // end class CommissionEmployee
```

I am lost on where to start on this. I understand that composition is a 'has-a' relationship and inheritance is an 'is-a'. Do I have to take this code and rewrite it using classes within classes?

Comment: ` // set first name` Comments like these serve no useful purpose and just clutter your code. Especially the `// end method name` pieces. Sometimes it makes sense to do that if it's long, confusing nested scopes, but proper indentation is usually a much better way to illustrate that.

Comment: Revell You may thing of composition as a set of Lego blocks put together. Class is not a block -- it is the definition of the block. An actual class instance is a block. Thus, the class definitions (think block definitions) can be located anywhere convenient (separate classesm inner classes etc.). By putting instances together (e.g. passing then as parameters into a constructor of a higher order class) a new construction gets created (e.g. a wall of several blocks).

Answer (score 1):

NOt necessarily.  Think about the interfaces or even some example code first.  You've got an Employee; that employee "has" base pay and commission.  Both of them are things that are likely to change more often than, say, the employee's SSAN, so they make sense to break out as classes on their own.

Now you have three classes (this is purposefully not in Java notation):

```
class Employee
    ssan : SocialSecurityNumber  // more classes I don't bother to define
    base : BasePay
    cmsn : Commission

    public setBasePay(base:BasePay)
    public getBasePay()
    public setCommission(cmsn:Commission)
    public getCommission()

    ... more stuff
end

class BasePay

    rate: DollarsPerHour

    public getPay(hr : Hours)
end

class Commission
    rate : Pct

    public getPay(sales : Dollars)
end
```

and somewhere you'll have something like

```
check.totalPay = employee.getBasePay().getPay(hrs) + // note thats an instance
                 employee.getCommision().getPay(totSales)
```

By the way, I find it useful to think these things out as if I had special classes for most everything, like DollarsPerHour.  You can eventually replace that with something like `double`, but while you're thinking about it, it helps to preserve the units and keep you from doing things like adding Dollars to Hours